# display partialview as popup in HttpGet div MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a new MVC application. My issue is to open a partialview in a div as popup. 
It works fine if I call a `$("#div").load()` method for a action method without any parameters. If there is any parameter it is not working at all.

**View:**

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create", "ActionName", ControllerName,new{Param1=Model.Param1,Param2=Model.Param2},new {@id="CreateNew" })
   <div id="DivCreateView"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#CreateNew').click(function() {
        debugger;
        var Param1 = $("#hdnValue").val();
        var Param2 = $("#hdnValue2").val();
        $.get(this.href, function(result) {
            debugger;
            var div = $("#DivCreateView");

            div.load("/ControllerName/ActionName"),

                div.dialog({
                    modal: true
                    , width: 600
                    , height: 600
                    , title: "Add Dialog"
                    , resizable: false
                    , close: function(event, ui) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult ActionName(int Param1, string Param2) {    
 Model vmModel = new Model();
 vmModel.Param1 = Param1;
 vmModel.Param2 = Param1;
 return PartialView(vmModel);
}
```

Scenarios i tried

1) Pass param only in ActionLink, is returning the view in a new window

2)if I pass parameter in load function as well as in actionLink. It is opening the view in a new window

3) Pass parameter only in ajax call, is giving the error "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter `Param1` of non-nullable type `System.Int32` for method `System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult ActionName(Int32, System.String)` in `Configurations.Controllers.ControllerName`. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters" with a URL generated with `?Length=`

4) If i give `actionlink` as  `@Html.ActionLink("Create", "ActionName", "ControllerName",null,new {@id="CreateNew" })`, is generating a URL without any parameter and same error as 3rd scenario.

Can anyone please help me, what am i doing wrong here

Comment: You pass the parameters in the 2nd parameter of `.load()` -
 `div.load("/ControllerName/ActionName", { Param1: Param1, Param2: Param2 })`

Comment: in ActionLink statement @Html.ActionLink("Create", "ActionName", "ControllerName",new {@id="CreateNew" }) should i leave like this??

Comment: You do not need it at all - it can be just `<a href="#" id="CreateNew">Create</a>` and then you do not need the `return false`. You also need to delete the `$.get()` code - there is no point making 2 ajax calls to the same method - all you need to the `.load()`

Comment: You have to pass param1 and param2 in the load method like below `div.load("/ControllerName/ActionName?Param1=Param1 & Param2=Param2"),`

Comment: And don't need the $get as you are already calling the load method

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, it worked but one query how to create this simple href using Html.ActionLink. Coz, if requires a actionName and linkText If I give the actionName same error as my 3rd scenario. If I use a html<a href > tag as mentioned by you, it Worked. Any way where i can use a simple Html.ActionLink

Comment: Why would you want to use `ActionLink()` - that is not only unnecessary, but pointless extra overhead

Comment: I thought in MVC, we should use only @Html, controls. my bad!. I will use the same.. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the values in the 2nd parameter of the `.load()` function. In addition, you making 2 calls to your method and you should use either `$.get()` or the `div.load()`, not both.

Start by generating you link using

```
<a href="#" id="CreateNew">Create</a>
```

then change you script to

```
var url = '@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")';
var div = $("#DivCreateView");
$('#CreateNew').click(function() {
    var Param1 = $("#hdnValue").val();
    var Param2 = $("#hdnValue2").val();
    div.load(url, { Param1: Param1, Param2 : Param2 }, function() {
        div.dialog({
            ....
        });      
    });
});
```

or alternatively (instead of `div.load()`)

```
$.get(url, { Param1: Param1, Param2 : Param2 }, function(data) {
    div.html(data);
    div.dialog({
        ....
    });
});
```